# Was gold an original color of J.C Higgins Jet Rocket 502-10? What year(s) was it manufactured?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I inherited this rare J.C Higgins Jet Rocket 502-10 and am looking for more information about it, specifically what year(s) it was manufactured. I have the original instruction manual for the Deluxe Bicycle Stand Exerciser #105W but not for the bike. The manual does not list a date. I assume the exerciser piece could be attached to various models. I have the basket, but it seems to be missing the attachment parts for it. Is 502-10 the serial or model number? I would like to know if this is the original paint colors or if it had been painted gold. Any info is helpful. Thank you.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MydUA.jpg]
[image]
[image]